# Project Euler Design Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

Is there a design pattern that lends itself to building a foundation of components to help solve Project Euler problems?  I've solved ~30 issues - and I find that I'll need to re-use functionality that was previously written (e.g primality checks).  Instead of writing static methods in a utility class, I was thinking of having a calculator interface - implemented by various concrete classes that will solve different sub problems.  I could then build on that as I solve increasingly complex problems - maybe?  Does anyone have any good suggestions?  I'm solving the problems in Java.

Comment: To what end? Just to get a warm and fuzzy feeling from doing it the object-oriented(tm) way? What's wrong with static methods?

Comment: I suppose you're right.  It's just feels like perhaps it can be written more elegently?  It seems unwieldly to have a ton of static methods.

Comment: I don't think we have enough information to answer your question.

Comment: What is missing in your opinion?

Comment: btw if you're open to other languages for solving Project Euler problems check out Python. it's easy to learn, very concise, and it facilitates number-crunching really well.

Comment: cool - i will do that.  thanks for the pointer Nathan

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are some functions that come in handy repeatedly, like for generating primes. You could keep a file with useful functions in them. Beyond that I don't think there is any benefit. Project Euler problems are more about the math than they are about complex programming, I expect that if you have to write a lot of code you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The classic pattern for this kind of things is the Template design pattern, but you can build it thinking in other design patterns like for example Visitor, it depends on your needs and taste.
You may find useful this link: [Template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)